# OP Character That takes the Ideal of God & spits on it

Tags: society

So, I have a character that goes by the name of Mod. He is part of a group of 'Adept' beings that exist beyond the universe. He takes the Ideology of there being 'Gods' and spits on it by, in a metaforical sense, 'raping' every discovery made in physics. Along with every discovery made in History, by him prooving that he was there, by either literally taking a dump on Cesar Agustus's Throne room, or going to the time of Adolf Hitler & inventing the selfie, before it was cool. Now, before you go on and say "Hey, he's too OP! kill it with fire!" I'll communicate two thing.
A: He's an adept being that can do whatever, he can't be killed with fire
B: He's Deus Ex Machina, to be of convenience in a story that is Stereotypically Unstereotypical (Example of said storytype is a Very strong character that is very homosexual in behavior, by literally having a boyfriend.)

And he's OP with good reason. He's kind of the motive why there are good people in the world, as he fixes people's lives by forcing his entry, fixing their lives,a nd exiting without leaving a trace of his existence.

So, my Question.
How can he be this OP, without being too annoying or too... overly "in-your-face" about being OP?

Comment: I don't really know what you are asking. This post also touches on a variety of controversial topics seemingly for the shock value. I am voting to close it.

Comment: I will accept your opinion, but rather go against it. Sure, I have no idea how most of this website works, but I mean... I'm starting out, so give me time.

Comment: As in: I know it touches on many topics, but I mean in the aspect of cahracter.

Comment: This *might* be a question for writers SE since this is probably more "how do I keep readers invested in this character" rather than "can this character exist", but I'm not that familiar with what is on topic for writers SE.

Comment: Actually, if this about people in the story liking him rather than the reader, My answer might not fit. Everyone in Star Trek hates Q. But he's still a lovable character.

Comment: I agree. But my objective of him is to be hated in the beginning & loved in the end, by building a level of trust.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please check out our short [tour].  I've put this on hold because it's hard to tell what you're asking, and because a lot of this seems to be more about shock value than worldbuilding.  Also, I don't know what you mean by OP in this context.  When you [edit] your question, it will go to a review queue for possible reopening.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend watching every "Q" episode of Star Trek (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(Star_Trek)) and [this](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Q)). Q is basically what you just described. And most of the episodes should be available on Netflix (and you don't really need to know the story up to that point to follow those episodes).

So now I'm going to try to explain all the things that add up to Q being both omnipotent and interesting.

First and foremost,

### He is fair

By this I mean, when he agrees to leave you alone (he usually doesn't but) he will leave you alone. While he DOES have the power to just bend everyone's will so that he always wins, he NEVER denies another persons free will (he will sometimes tempt them though).

### He is in check

An single omnipotent being can easily snap and do what ever they want. However, the existence of other omnipotent being who can and will strip his powers and/or limits how much he can actually interfere, helps the reader to trust that there are lines that this omnipotent being will never cross.

### He is socially crippled

I don't mean as in can't interact with people, but he is out of touch with the 'common man'. He knows their language, he knows their mannerisms, but he doesn't really understand how a normal person thinks and feels. This often comes off as him being egocentric and wild.

### Final notes

His lack of social grace, combined with his limited direct interference means that while he CAN just win, the reader grows a respect for the character because he can **play the game and lose like anyone else**. The reader doesn't care that he has an "I win" button on hand because the reader believes he will never use it (and will lose all respect for him if he does). But really, this kind of character is *hard to pull off right*, and I highly recommend watching the Q episodes of Star Trek for refrence. (And since someone will mention it, there is also [Discord](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Discord) from My Little Pony, but he does violate the first point once, and he lossly violates the second point, so he is a weaker example in my opinion)

Comment: Wow, this is very descriptive, and I love how you pointed out almost evrything. Here are some things that stack up with the description you gave me:
He is fair - Mod is... give or take fair. I mean, he's like... non-linear with his OP-ness. He can have a victory, as much a loss.
He is in Check - Ha! (sorry) He has no one nor himself to keep him in place. He knows when to intrude & when not to, btu is very... eh.

Comment: He is socially crippled - He is up to par with the norms of the times he is in. Well... He might not know certain things, but he knows others. Perse, he's like Uncle grandpa from Cartoon Network, but more... normal.

Comment: @JakeRGlezII socially crippled might be a bit... strongly worded... Q can interact with people just fine, but he is not a master manipulator. He cannot perfectly predict peoples reactions and how they will act. So like chess is game a normal human (who is good at chess) can beat him in (since chess is more or less a psychological battle).

Comment: I see where you're going at, and I'll say this: He knows what moves are coming next, if he focues enugh. He just chooses to not use the game to his favor, seeming as he doesn't know, but knows. Playing like he's guessing but he isn't. He can also interact with people, but to a certain extent. Like he can make himself visible to only one person at a time or two. Heck, maybe 3.

Comment: @JakeRGlezII I think for the reader, it really boils down to, from their point of view, did the hero win because he played better? Or did the hero just win because the psudo-god let him? From the reader's perspective, how fair was the 'game', and how much does the reader trust the psudo-god to always be fair?

Comment: The thing about that is: Mod is trustworthy to the level of how you would trust an FBI agent to not leak intel into Wikileaks.